# Spotify spark-bigquery connector issue while using BigQuerySelect method from Dataproc cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, spotify, google-cloud-dataproc

I am new to BigQuery GCP and to access BigQuery data we are using Spotify spark-bigquery connector as provided [here](https://github.com/spotify/spark-bigquery).

We are able to use `sqlContext.bigQueryTable("project_id:dataset.table")` and its working.

When we are using `sqlContext.bigQuerySelect("SELECT * FROM [project_id:dataset.table]")` it is giving error:

```
The user xyz-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have permission to query table.
```

We have done necessary settings w.r.t json file and location. But don't have any clue about from where it is taking this user account details.

Please provide help regarding its cause and how to fix it in code.

Comment: We have resolved it by creating json file and then setting export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_service_account_file> on dataproc cluster because we are using it on dataproc cluster. But don't know cause of  this way of working of API.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the service account you are using (xyz-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com) doesn’t have enough [IAM permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control). You should go to your IAM settings and make sure it has at least BigQuery Data Viewer permissions.

Comment: We have set credentials json file as indicated by API but now sure from where it is taking this xyz account. There is no such account details we have provided and here xyz is some number. As i mentioned above same thing is working with bigQueryTable table method and it is reading data then why bigQuerySelect is not working.

Comment: Setting the JSON sets up the account to be used, but it doesn't give it the permissions it needs. You should check in "Service accounts" from "IAM & admin" in your GCP console and see if this service account has enough permissions. Your bigQueryTable statement works that's just a configuration statement and doesn't need any specific permissions, while bigQuerySelect needs at least read permissions on your data.

Comment: Hi Agreed rillia you are close to it but from where it is taking this random account is the question?

Comment: If you have the Compute Engine API enabled, a Compute Engine Service account is created for you, with the email PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com, it's probably that one (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)